# jQuery Validation - Select Multidimensional Array at least 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can i validate the following using jQuery Validation . The user must at least select 1 of the option below.

```
<select name="quantity[adult][seat_a]" class="group-required">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="quantity[adult][seat_b]" class="group-required">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="quantity[adult][seat_c]" class="group-required">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just a notice: You have to validate the input on server side again. jQuery should only be used to give a fast an user friendly response if there is any invalid input.

Comment: Show us your call to the `.validate()` method.

Answer (score 2):

To mandate that at least one out of these `select` elements are selected, you would use [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) which is part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    rules: {
        "quantity[adult][seat_a]": {
            require_from_group: [1, ".group-required"]
        },
        "quantity[adult][seat_b]": {
            require_from_group: [1, ".group-required"]
        },
        "quantity[adult][seat_c]": {
            require_from_group: [1, ".group-required"]
        }
    },
    groups: {
        myGroup: "quantity[adult][seat_a] quantity[adult][seat_b] quantity[adult][seat_c]"   
    }
});
```

This will create a simultaneous & identical error message on all three `select` elements.   Use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to combine these into one and [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place the resulting message into your layout.

**Important**:  You also need the `value` of the default `option` of every `select` to be empty.  Otherwise, the plugin thinks `0` is the user's selection and nothing will be validated.

```
<select name="quantity[adult][seat_a]" class="group-required">
    <option value="">0</option>
    ....
```

OR...

```
<select name="quantity[adult][seat_a]" class="group-required">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    ....
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have a huge number of elements and do not wish to declare them individually within `.validate()`, then use the `.rules('add')` method within a jQuery `.each()`.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
});

$('.group-required').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, '.group-required']
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/n1z0Lufw/**

Additionally, using the `groups` option to consolidate error messages, again without having to declare each field name manually...

```
var names = "";
$('.group-required').each(function() {
    names += $(this).attr('name') + " ";
});
names = $.trim(names);

$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    groups: {
        myGroup: names
    }
});

$('.group-required').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, '.group-required']
    });
});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/scmuxq53/**

Comment: Sparky how about when there is a huge number of selection.