# jQuery Validate groups option issue with names using dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validate plugin and I need to group messages for a group of inputs, but their name values contain a dot and that seems to be a problem. Is there any way to overcome the issue?

```
    groups: {
        validDateOfBirth: 'firstname.fieldOne firstname.fieldTwo',

    },
```

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show more code.  Where is the relevant HTML for the form elements and the rest of the `.validate()` method?

Comment: People took time to answer your question.  At least you could take the time to respond to them.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, within the `groups` option, you cannot use names if they contain special characters.   Within the `rules` option, you'd surround the names with quotes [as per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)).  But unfortunately, that trick does not work for the `groups` option.

However, there is one workaround.  You would construct the parameter outside of the `.validate()` method and assign it to a variable.  Then insert the variable itself within `.validate()`.

For your case, I use a jQuery "starts with" selector to grab all `input` elements that start with `firstname`.  You could use something else instead, like a `class`, if you want, as long as you only select all elements for this particular grouping.

```
var names = "";                                 // create empty string
$('input[name^="firstname"]').each(function() { // grab each input starting w/ 'firstname'
    names += $(this).attr('name') + " ";        // append each name + single space to string
});
names = $.trim(names);                          // remove the empty space from the end

$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    groups: {
        validDateOfBirth: names  // reference the string
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wpzk47t8/**

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28029469/594235

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use something different than dot for field name, because you may have problems, see [What characters are allowed in the HTML Name attribute inside input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424860/what-characters-are-allowed-in-the-html-name-attribute-inside-input-tag#answer-13858670)

Comment: Dots ***are*** allowed in the `name` attribute.

Comment: I didn't say that they are not allowed, I just said that it **may** not work for some browsers/environments.

Comment: Dots are allowed, so simply saying _"you may have problems"_ without a self-contained explanation is not good enough.