# Jquery Validate checkbox (at least one for group) in a complex form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've a very complex form with X groups of checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-block1">
 <input id="package-1-1" name="member[1][package][19]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="100" style="float: left;">
 <input id="package-1-2" name="member[1][package][234]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="300" style="float: left;">
 <input id="package-1-3" name="member[1][package][254]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="500" style="float: left;">
</div>
<div class="checkbox-block2">
 <input id="package-2-1" name="member[2][package][19]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="100" style="float: left;">
 <input id="package-2-2" name="member[2][package][234]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="300" style="float: left;">
 <input id="package-2-3" name="member[2][package][254]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="500" style="float: left;">
</div>
```

I need to validate the form with a rules that require at least on checkbox for group/block.
I try with:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myform-s3").validate({
                rules: {
                    'member[1]': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1
                    },
                    'member[2]': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1
                    },
                    'member[3]': {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1
                    }
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if ( element.is(':radio') || element.is(':checkbox') ) {
                        error.insertBefore( element.next() );
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter( element );
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                    alert('valid form');
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

But I got "Valid Form" also when no checkbox is selected.

**P.S:**
Number of blocks are selected by the user in a previous form, then I can have 1, 2, 3 or more blocks of checkboxes.

Comment: Solution is simple if you can have same `name` on all checkboxes within each group.   In that case `required` works by default.

Comment: I've not the same name, member[x]...

Comment: Obviously.  I’m suggesting that you do it that way instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code...

```
rules: {
    'member[1]': {  // <- MUST be the NAME of input element
```

`member[1]` is not the `name` of anything so nothing is going to happen.  You cannot use partial names or selectors here, just the actual value of the `name` attribute.

---

### **Solution 1**

To validate a group of checkboxes, you need them all to share the same `name`...

```
<div class="checkbox-block1">
    <input id="package-1-1" name="member[1]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="100" style="float: left;">
    <input id="package-1-2" name="member[1]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="300" style="float: left;">
    <input id="package-1-3" name="member[1]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="500" style="float: left;">
</div>
```

And then you can simply use the `required` rule all by itself...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform-s3").validate({
        rules: {
            'member[1]': {
                required: true
            }, ....
```

**DEMO 1:  https://jsfiddle.net/1an60fxy/**

---

### **Solution 2**

If you cannot alter the naming, then you must dynamically declare the rules using the `.rules()` method and a "starts with", `^=`, selector.

Do not declare the rules within `.validate()`...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform-s3").validate({
        rules: {
            // other fields maybe
        ....
```

Use the `.rules()` method with an `.each()` and the `required_from_group` rule.  Note, `required_from_group` is part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js).

```
$('[name^="member[1]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, $('[id^="package-1"]')]
    });
});
```

Where `1` is the minimum number required from the group and `$('[id^="package-1"]')` targets all members of the group.

**DEMO 2: [jsfiddle.net/1an60fxy/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/1an60fxy/2/)**

With this version, you get duplicated messages that you will have to handle with [the `groups` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups).  Since your form is complex and dynamic, you will need to construct this option dynamically before you call `.validate()`.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28282183/594235).

```
var names1 = ""; // create empty string
$('[id^="package-1"]').each(function() { // grab each input starting w/ the class
    names1 += $(this).attr('name') + " "; // append each name + single space to string
});
names1 = $.trim(names1); // remove the empty space from the end

$("#myform-s3").validate({
    groups: {
        myGroup: names1 // reference the string
    }, 
    ....
```

**DEMO 2b: [jsfiddle.net/1an60fxy/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/1an60fxy/3/)**

Comment: Uhm, I'll try your solution later, for now thanks, but then I need to scroll the groups with a for to check every blocks of checkbox?

Comment: @natas, there's no other way.  You either make the `name` conform to `required` OR you use `require_from_group` and will have to deal with duplicate messages.